# Basic mobile layout with Backbone Boilerplate and Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to build my first application using Backbone.js and Backbone.Marionette and because it's my first time I'm a little bit lost on how everything has to "work".

My app will have two panels you can slide to (left, menu and right a chat), also a fixed header and the `div#content` that will be the one that changes. Just like that:

[image: skeleton]

So, I think that `div#menu` doesn't have to be on the DOM... it must be loaded by the App because there is somethings (like a profile avatar) that depends on the data that the App has to fetch before so it's OK that must be rendered. So... back to the start, `div#menu` must be a Marionette region? And then attach a View that will render the avatar, name and the menu items?

Then, what about `div#header`? This is just a name and 2 buttons to load the left or right panel, nothing more. Should I export this to a view too?

The chat probably it's the second part (`div#content` will be the first) that has more changes, people going online/offline... so it will change every 10-15 seconds so it makes sense that it's re-rendered. It must be a region too?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're on the right track. It depends on your preference, but this could all be a "Layout" that has a "region" for each area you've described. And each of those areas could be tied to an ItemView.